# Why isn't my UILabel being changed?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, uilabel

Why isn't my UILabel being changed? I am using the following code, and nothing is happening:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    percentCorrect.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth;
    percentCorrect.numberOfLines = 3;
    percentCorrect.minimumFontSize = 100;
}
```

Here is my Implemintation code:

```
- (void) updateScore {
    double percentScore = 100.0 * varRight / (varWrong + varRight);
    percentCorrect.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%", percentScore];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    percentCorrect.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    percentCorrect.numberOfLines = 3;
    percentCorrect.minimumFontSize = 100;
    percentCorrect.text = @"sesd";
}


- (void)correctAns {
    numberRight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Correct", varRight];
}

-(void)wrongAns {
    numberWrong.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i Incorrect", varWrong];
}

#pragma mark Reset Methods
- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender; {
    NSString *message = @"Are you sure you would like to reset?";
    self.wouldYouLikeToReset = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reset?" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [wouldYouLikeToReset addButtonWithTitle:@"Continue"];
    [self.wouldYouLikeToReset show];
    // Now goes to (void)alertView and see's what is being pressed!
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cancel button pressed");
    }
    else
    {
        varRight = 0;
        varWrong = 0;
        [self wrongAns];
        [self correctAns];
        percentCorrect.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0.0%%"];

    }
}

#pragma mark Button Action Methods

- (IBAction)right:(id)sender; {
    varRight++;
    [self correctAns];
    [self updateScore];
}

- (IBAction)wrong:(id)sender; {
    varWrong++;
    [self wrongAns];
    [self updateScore];
}


- (IBAction)subOneRight:(id)sender {
    if (varRight > 0 ) {
        varRight--;
        [self correctAns];
        [self updateScore];
    }
}


- (IBAction)subOneWrong:(id)sender {
    if (varWrong > 0) {
        varWrong--;
        [self wrongAns];
        [self updateScore];
    }
}

-(IBAction)addHalfCredit:(id)sender;
{
    varWrong++;
    varRight++;
    [self wrongAns];
    [self correctAns];
    [self updateScore];
}


@end
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: that line should be: [percentCorrect adjustFontSizeToFitWidth];

Comment: it should be percentCorrect.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

Answer (score 20):

1. In order for the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` setting to come into effect, the `numberOfLines` property must be set to 1. It won't work if it's != 1.
2. Are `awakeFromNib`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` being called at all?
3. The `minimumFontSize` property will do nothing if the text fits in the current bounds with the current font. Did you set the font property for the label?

   `percentCorrect.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];`
4. Finally, isn't a `minimumFontSize = 100` a little too big for a min font size?

Comment: This is the correct answer. The UILabel class reference for the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth property states "This property is effective only when the numberOfLines property is set to 1."

Comment: @chrispix correct, this worked for me. (I'm using MonoTouch and it works in the exact same way.)

Comment: @ettore about `minimumFontSize = 100` being to big for a min font size:  
Imagine a scenario where you want to make a text field that aligns with an image that sits above the field.  In that case it makes sense to set `minimumFontSize` quite big: `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` ONLY reduces the fontSize, it will not scale a fontSize up.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure everything is hooked up correctly. Make sure the IBOutlet for the `UITextfield` is setup and set break points within the method and see that the code is being touched. If it is, it's possible `percentCorrect` hasn't been hooked up correctly.

Comment: Everything is hooped up, because the label is responding to my IBActions

Comment: Can you change anything on that label programmatically in other methods? The IBActions can still be called without the IBOutlet being hooked up, so make sure the label is definitely hooked up as the IBOutlet

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to `init` your label if it is in the nib. If you are, then you created the label twice. So who knows which one you are messaging to. As soon as you initialized the label, you leaked the first one. So the label you have on screen is NOT the one you are manipulating in code.

Try placing your code in `viewDidLoad` instead. It should be initialized by then.

If that doesn't work, try `viewDidAppear:` simply to try to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `percentCorrect` hasn't yet been initialized.  Is `percentCorrect` equal to `nil` when that function is called, by any chance?  If so, wait until after it's properly initialized to set its properties.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to happen? Does the label show when your code is commented out? How is percentCorrect defined in the nib?

Have you tried:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    percentCorrect.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    percentCorrect.numberOfLines = 3;
    percentCorrect.minimumFontSize = 100;
    percentcorrent.text = @"What is the text in percentCorrect?";
}
```

Comment: Nope. Still not working :/

I added my code into the question, so maybe there is a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Seems that setText doesn't automatically force a redraw when the change happens on a non-main thread.  UI updates should always be done on the main thread to ensure responsiveness.  There's another way to force it, using a selector:

```
label = [[UILabel alloc] init];   //assumes label is a data member of some class
...
(some later method where you want to update the label)
...
[label performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText) withObject:@"New label value" waitUntilDone:false];
```

You may also get results from simply saying:

```
[label setNeedsDisplay];
```

which will force the update internally, but at the SDK's discretion.  I found that didn't work for me, thus why I recommend the selector on the main thread.

Comment: Messages to UIKit classes and instances thereof, and calls to UIKit functions, should always be done on the main thread **period**. See the recently-updated docs: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH5-SW40

Answer (score 0):

What I found is sometimes , don't rely too much on IB , just add a line to set the frame :

```
labelx.frame=CGRectMake(labelx.frame.origin.x,labelx.frame.origin.y, 300, labelx.frame.size.height);
```

Then , autoresize works !