# Adding and Editing a Dynamic UILabel Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dynamic, uilabel

Hey I am having some difficulty adding a dynamic label to my uiview subclass and have it scale itself properly. Here is the code I am using currently:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
   CGRect lblFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100,100);
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    testLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:lblFrame];
    testLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    testLbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    testLbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [testLbl setText:@"T"];
    testLbl.numberOfLines = 1;
    testLbl.minimumFontSize = 50;
    testLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [self addSubview:testLbl];
    }
return self;
}
```

This adds the label to the uiview but its text does not adjust. I have tried everything at the moment. Has anybody got any ideas?

Comment: @rckoenes: it looks like Conor has not gotten answers to most of his questions, so I wouldn't criticize him for being at 20%.

Comment: @Mus: Agreed. I do the same. Just thought you meant literally unanswered, rather than unsatisfactorily answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957918/why-isnt-my-uilabel-being-changed/3313834#3313834), the `.minimumFontSize` property is ignored if the text already fits within the label with the current font. Try setting the label font explicitly like this:

```
testLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting

```
testLbl.minimumFontSize = 50;
```

which is a ridiculously big font (one letter probably does not fit), so it probably tries to adjust but can't actually show anything because of your high minimum font size. Try something like

```
testLbl.minimumFontSize = 14;
```

I don't know what the behaviour is if the minimumFontSize is more that the actual specified font size, maybe it just gives up...